# Using react-bootstrap-table-next and react-bootstrap-table2-paginator to implement Jump To Page Button

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am newbie to React and trying to implement 'Jump To Page' functionality using Boot Strap Table with Pagination. Below is the code

`import React, { Component} from 'react'
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next'
import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
import paginationFactory, { PaginationProvider,PaginationTotalStandalone} from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
class Product extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.onPageChange = this.onPageChange.bind(this);
        this.handleOnchage = this.handleOnchage.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            activePage: 1,
            columns: [{
                dataField: 'rowNumber',
                text: 'Serial Number',
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { width: "10%" };
                }
              },
              {
                dataField: 'word',
                text: 'Word',
                sort: true,
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { width: "20%" };
                }
              }, {
                dataField: 'count',
                text: 'Count',
                sort: true,
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { width: "10%" };
                }
              }, {
                dataField: 'fileNames',
                text: 'File Names',
                headerStyle: () => {
                    return { textAlign: "left" };
                }
              }
            ]           
        }
    }

    handleOnchage(e) {
        this.setState({activePage: e.target.value});
    }
    
    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.onPageChange(this.state.activePage);     
    }

    onPageChange(page) {
        console.log("in onPageChange page="+page);
        if(page){
            if(this.state.activePage !== page){
                this.setState({activePage: page});
            }     
            console.log("in onPageChange page="+page+" activePage="+this.state.activePage);
        } 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://10.0.0.18:8080/list-words")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
        .catch(error => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        })
    }

    render() {

        const customTotal = (from, to, size) => (
            <span className="react-bootstrap-table-pagination-total">
              Showing { from } to { to } of { size } Results
            </span>
        );

        const options = {
            paginationSize: 25,
            alwaysShowAllBtns: true,
            firstPageText: 'First',
            prePageText: 'Back',
            nextPageText: 'Next',
            lastPageText: 'Last',
            nextPageTitle: 'First page',
            prePageTitle: 'Pre page',
            firstPageTitle: 'Next page',
            lastPageTitle: 'Last page',
            showTotal: true,
            paginationTotalRenderer: customTotal,
            totalSize: this.state.data.length,
            onPageChange: this.onPageChange
          };

        const contentTable = ({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => (
            <div>
                <div align="left">
                    <input name="activePage"
                          value={this.state.activePage}
                          onChange={this.handleOnchage} />
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Jump to Page</button>                
                </div>
              <ToolkitProvider
                keyField="rowNumber"
                data={this.state.data} selector
                columns={this.state.columns}
                search
                loading={true}
              >
                {
                  toolkitprops => (
                    <div>
                      <div align="left"><SearchBar { ...toolkitprops.searchProps } />
                      <PaginationTotalStandalone { ...paginationProps }/></div><br/>
                      <BootstrapTable
                        striped
                        hover
                        { ...toolkitprops.baseProps }
                        { ...paginationTableProps }
                      />
                    </div>
                  )
                }
              </ToolkitProvider>
            </div>
        );  

        return (
            <PaginationProvider
                pagination={
                    paginationFactory(options)
                }
            >
                { contentTable }
            </PaginationProvider>
        )
    }
}

const { SearchBar } = Search;

export default Product;`

When I enter a page number and click on the button, I see that onPageChange being called, but it doesn't render the boot strap table or jump to that Page. Rest of other functionality is working fine. I can search, I can click on pages to jump to them. Please let me know what am I missing. 
`"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-bootstrap-table": "^4.3.1",
"react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
"react-bootstrap-table2-filter": "^1.3.3",
"react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.3",`